# Can a single QFT field configuration be written as a set of spinor/vector valued functions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, spinors, quantum-states, gauge

If a QFT state is a probability distribution over field configurations, then a single field configuration must correspond to an observable situation, right?  As far as I can gather, each field configuration specifies the numbers of all particle species, and the position or momentum, and maybe spin, of each particle.

Now, my impression is that the states are typically represented in a much more abstract way, that I clearly have a lot of trouble wrapping my head around.  But in principle (even if it's not the most efficient way), could we write a field configuration as a set of Dirac-spinor-valued functions of spacetime -- one for each fermion species -- and accompanying vector-valued functions for the gauge bosons?  And if we can, then how would that work?  For example, if I just have two electrons, and I know their positions, would the spinor function be a sum of two different delta functions?  And what would the possibilities for the photon vector field then be?  Surely it must be at least partially determined by the presence of the two point charges...

And what if you specify the momenta of the two electrons instead?  Would the spinor field be a sum of two plane waves?  But if so, wouldn't the EM field of those electrons also have to be completely delocalized?  And doesn't that mean you wouldn't get any directional preference, ie. scattering?  So to model scattering, does the wave-functional necessarily have to contain a distribution over momenta so as to have a localized wave-packet?

Or does the interaction mean that a two-particle momentum eigenstate is no longer a simple sum of plane waves?  Then how does that happen?  In basic QM, the eigenstate was modified by the *known external* potential, but now the potential is generated by the particles themselves, and their positions are completely unknown!

And are position and momentum essentially the only eigenstates we can use to build up these multi-particle states?

These are the questions that seem physically tangible to me, but everything I read jumps immediately into a highly abstract formalism, and as much as I try to read about Fock space, creation operators, etc., I can't help feeling that it's an endless vortex that isn't getting closer to the point where the state meets reality!  But when they were building these theories back in the 40's and such, surely there was a more intuitive, if less streamlined, way to describe what they were doing?  Maybe there's a source that presents it a little closer to the language I'm using here?  Thanks for reading this!

Comment: Hello Adam! I understand your confusion, your questions are very reasonable, the truth is that QFT is taught horribly badly and almost any book you'll find skips crucial conceptual clarifications and gets too technical too fast. If you still need it I would recommend you getting Robert Klauber's "Student Friendly Quantum Field Theory" which is a book way more gentle than most QFT texts. It has a section literally covering your question about wave packets (which by the way you DON'T need to calculate transition amplitudes -- surprising as it is you only need momentum eigenstates for that).

Comment: You get regular QM if you replace the (eg. position and momentum) observables of classical mechanics with non-commuting (not interchangeable -- the order in which you use them matters) operators. Then, your observables will act on abstract entitites, called "states" or wavefunctions and the eigenvalues of your operators are possible values you would get if you measured your system in the real world.

Comment: In QFT you do pretty much the same thing only in this case you don't have one position -- you have a whole field (and its conjugate momentum field). Then, your field becomes the "position operator" that will act on your abstract states. Theoretically this means that (like with position in QM) this time your field will not have a definite configuration anymore. If you were to measure it at any time, you would get different oscillatiory modes with different probabilities.

Comment: Now, back in the classical realm you had a relativistic wave equation (eg. Klein-Gordon equation, Dirac equation). Relativistic means that its solutions are not defined on normal 3D Euclidian space, instead, they are waves in the Minkowski spacetime of special relativity. If you solve the equation you can find simple plane wave solutions (analogous to sine waves). If you add up all the possible modes of these plane waves (there are infinitely many) it's like you decomposed your (still classical!) field into a bunch of Fourier-modes.

Comment: So your (classical) field at one point can be written as an infinite sum (integral) over all possible modes. In the mathematical expression for this there is a constant in front of each mode which is just a number. This one point of your field described by the superposition of every single mode moves (changes its value is a better word) in exactly the same way as a harmonic oscillator does (it increases and decreases with a certain frequency). So your field is behaving as if every single point of it were a harmonic oscillator so you can quantize your field in the same way.

Comment: When you promote your field to an operator these constants in front of the modes become creation and annihilation operators (operating in momentum space, NOT position space). This means that a given mode's creation operator will put a quantum of energy into every single oscillator that makes up your field. Your STATES are a system of an infinite number of harmonic oscillator modes, so they look something like |0,0,0,1...> or |1,1,1,0...>. It's important to understand that these states are not the modes themselves but they are probability distributions over possible modes the field could take.

Comment: If you wanted to (I've never seen an explicit example for this in any textbook though -- probably because you never need it. Also physicists I had the misfortune to stumble upon on this website were less than willing to help.) you could write a wavefunctional e.g. for the vacuum state |0,0,0,0...> which would give you the probability that you would observe your field in a certain mode when it's in this state.

Comment: I think one of the confusions your (excellent) questions come from is the failure to grasp that QFT is (1) a statistical theory (2) different quantum particles are indistinguishable. It's not like you have one electron here and one electron there and then let's calculate what they will do. Instead you say: I have a multiparticle field in this state (with n particles in this energy level and m particles in that -- crucial concept: occupation number representation!) and I want to know how likely it is to get into another state.

Comment: Then you don't look at little electron wave packets that will meet in some particular place but instead when you're doing your calculations you integrate over all space and get a statistical amplitude that something will happen. So when you see an X and Y point in a Feynman diagram, it's not like there is literally an X and Y point somewhere where the particles are in space but instead you are integrating over all possible X's and Y's (a similar idea to the path integral).

Comment: @IstvánBauer  Thanks a lot for the very extensive insight, among other things I think it pretty much hammers home the point that there's no real way to learn this stuff without diving into these off-putting concepts.  But I really appreciate the link to the textbook, I'm going to start reading it and see where it leads.  By the way, do you happen to know of a full text PDF link for it?

Comment: Yes, it's a sad truth but QFT is definitely not something you can just do or even understand without having a deep background in math and physics. Most physics undergraduates will not even have touched it. What makes it hard is the fact that it combines relativity and QM which are both pretty advanced and counterintuitive even as separate subjects.

Comment: If you google "Student friendly quantum field theory pdf" one of the first results should be "qdoc.tips". That link worked perfectly for me.

Comment: This book is the best I have found up to this day. If you still find it too complicated, then if you are really dedicated I would recommend that you put QFT aside for a while and do a full course on the maths of special relativity, QM, relativistic QM and group theory. After you have these down, it will go perfectly well.